# Facebook debugger reports "Circular redirect path detected" (301) on certain website

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, circular-reference

Why isn't the [Facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) able to parse http://www.brandenburg-business-guide.de/ ? It reports `301 Circular redirect path detected`. However, there is actually no redirection in place. Also apache's `access.log` reports no retrievals by facebook.

See https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.brandenburg-business-guide.de%2F and hit `Debug` button.

Answer (score 2):

The page does not contain any **OpenGraph** meta tags. Check out the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects/#selfhosted-creating).

Facebook scraper expects the page to contain `og:url` meta tag which will serve as the canonical url **OR** link tag with **rel="canonical"**. Since the document is missing both, Facebook cannot decide what is the canonical url, hence the circular redirect path error.

For a reference, try [Goodreads](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.goodreads.com%2F) debugging information.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx, you might be right, I'll check it. The funny thing is that Facebook does not seem to attempt to retrieve the website after I enter my site in their debugger. That is, there are absolutely no traces in the `access.log`. I always thought that the FB debugger  wouldn't cache website content but always try to access/parse the website immediately?!

Comment: FB debugger does not cache response. When you use FB debugger, it scrapes the website at that moment and caches it when that object is used on actual facebook site. I think your web access log output is being redirected to some other file, because there is no way facebook scraper does not show up. BTW facebook debugger user agent string: `facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)`