# facebook share tool reports non existing circular redirects in wordpress article

Tags: wordpress, facebook, redirect, facebook-opengraph

I am seeing circular redirects in the Facebook Sharing tool I cannot explain on a post written in Wordpress:

This is not as [Facebook debugger reports "Circular redirect path detected" (301) on certain website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22226981/facebook-debugger-reports-circular-redirect-path-detected-301-on-certain-web) : I have the `og:url` metadata defined in the page

- WordPress post: http://tademo.trueanthem.com/evergreen/posting-just-fun/996/ -> You can see is has the right og:url meta: `<meta property="og:url" content="http://tademo.trueanthem.com/evergreen/posting-just-fun/996/" />` and also `<link rel="canonical" href="http://tademo.trueanthem.com/evergreen/posting-just-fun/996/" />`
- Facebook Sharing Debugging Tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Ftademo.trueanthem.com%2Fevergreen%2Fposting-just-fun%2F996%2F
- The detected canonical page is chopping the last `/996/` from the or:url/link canonical

[These are the reported redirects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhlZN.png)

I run curl to check if there was a redirect, and there is no redirect:

```
$ curl -IL 'http://tademo.trueanthem.com/evergreen/check-ga-ia/986/'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 06 Nov 2017 18:15:49 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=20
X-Pingback: http://tademo.trueanthem.com/xmlrpc.php
Link: <http://tademo.trueanthem.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
Link: <http://tademo.trueanthem.com/?p=986>; rel=shortlink
X-Cacheable: SHORT
Vary: Accept-Encoding,Cookie
Cache-Control: max-age=600, must-revalidate
X-Cache: MISS
X-Pass-Why:
X-Cache-Group: normal
X-Type: default

$
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like the Facebook crawler does not like the 3 digits at the end of the permalink. I removed the 3 digits in the permalink for all posts, and now the Facebook Sharing Tool has no problem.